# How to delete a part of the htmlparse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, html-parsing, html-parser

I make htmlparse of a webpage and i get a DOM of the page with this chunk:

```
 { raw: 'td',
   data: 'td',
   type: 'tag',
   name: 'td',
   children: [ { raw: '600', data: '600', type: 'text' } ] },
```

How can i delete all of the types "text" of that htmlparse? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete all text nodes recursively you could do it like this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var deleteText = function(node) {
    if (!node.children || node.children.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Exclude text nodes
    node.children = _.filter(node.children, function(child) {
        return child.type !== 'text';
    });

    // Recurse over child nodes
    _.each(node.children, deleteText);
};

deleteTextNodes(parsed);
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `delete` there. Just use `.splice()`. And FYI your recursive call needs `Nodes` at the end.

Comment: Also, you're modifying the array during a forward iteration. This will cause it to skip a node every time one is removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete any children with type of text, just loop over all your children and use array.splice to remove the once with a type of text.

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output'),
    htmlParse = { raw: 'td',
                     data: 'td',
                     type: 'tag',
                     name: 'td',
                     children: [
                       { raw: '600', data: '600', type: 'text' },
                       { raw: '100', data: '100', type: 'num' }
                     ] 
                    };

for(var i = 0; i < htmlParse.children.length; i++) {
  if (htmlParse.children[i].type === "text") {
    htmlParse.children.splice(i, 1);
  } 
}
output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(htmlParse);
console.log(htmlParse);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```